# Cannot create postgres database with Doctrine

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have project in Symfony2 with doctrine. In one moment i loose ability to create/drop databases via console commands like

```
app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
app/console doctrine:database:create
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

If i attemp to create database, doctrine give me next error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                                     
  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  database "motherhood" does not exist
```

So, i can create database in psql with user, written in symfony config. If i try to drop existing database via Doctrine, it gives me this:

```
SQLSTATE[55006]: Object in use: 7 ERROR:  database "motherhood" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session using the database.
```

But there is no connection to this database

Comment: getting the same error myself. doctrine is ignoring the config parameter for database_name: and telling me that a database with the name of database_user: from the config does not exist when  I do like you app/console doctrine:database:create . Well naturally that doesn't exist, the database that exists is the one specified by database_name not database_user.   very frustrating for new symfony users

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix for the problem is to create a database with the same name as user executing the command, because PostgreSQL must connect to a database, even when creating a new one.

The failure when dropping the database should be fixed in DoctrineBundle 1.4.

The failure to create the database will be fixed in doctrine/dbal in the very next release (2.5.2) as mentioned here: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/402 . The problem will be fixed by always connection to the template database, which cannot be dropped.